# How to bind volumes in docker-py?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I think this used to work up to a few months ago. The regular commandline docker:

```
>> docker run --name 'mycontainer' -d -v '/new' ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'touch /new/hello.txt'
>> docker run --volumes-from mycontainer ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'ls new'
>> hello.txt
```

works as expected but I cannot get this to work in docker-py:

```
from docker import Client #docker-py
import time

docker = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
response1 = docker.create_container('ubuntu', detach=True, volumes=['/new'],
    command="/bin/bash -c 'touch /new/hello.txt'", name='mycontainer2')
docker.start(response1['Id'])
time.sleep(1)
response = docker.create_container('ubuntu', 
    command="/bin/bash -c 'ls new'", 
    volumes_from='mycontainer2')
docker.start(response['Id'])
time.sleep(1)
print(docker.logs(response['Id']))
```

..always tells me that new doesn't exist. How is `volumes-from` supposed to be done with docker-py?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is the current working way to do volume bindings:

```
volumes= ['/host_location']
volume_bindings = {
                    '/host_location': {
                        'bind': '/container_location',
                        'mode': 'rw',
                    },
}

host_config = client.create_host_config(
                    binds=volume_bindings
)

container = client.create_container(
                    image='josepainumkal/vwadaptor:jose_toolUI',
                    name=container_name,
                    volumes=volumes,
                    host_config=host_config,
) 
response = client.start(container=container.get('Id'))
```

Comment: How would you do this with named volumes that are already running?

Answer (score 5):

The original answer has been deprecated in the api and no longer works. Here is how you would do it by using the create host config commands

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

container = client.create_container(
    image='ubuntu',
    stdin_open=True,
    tty=True,
    command='/bin/sh',
    volumes=['/mnt/vol1', '/mnt/vol2'],

    host_config=client.create_host_config(binds={
        '/tmp': {
            'bind': '/mnt/vol2',
            'mode': 'rw',
        },
        '/etc': {
            'bind': '/mnt/vol1',
            'mode': 'ro',
        }
    })
)
client.start(container)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from docker api version 1.10 `volumes-from` is an argument to `start()` instead of `create()`

Available from [docker-py release 0.3.2](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-py/tree/0.3.2)

Pull request which introduced the change: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-py/pull/200

Comment: The mentioned change is available from [docker-py 0.3.2](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-py/tree/0.3.2)