# Creating and mounting volumes with docker.py

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I've been looking through the documentation and some tutorials but I cannot seem to find anything current on how to create a volume using the `docker.py` library. Nothing I've found appears to be current as the `create_host_config()` method appears to be non-existent. Any help in solving this issue or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all of you.

I've searched the documentation on:
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
https://github.com/docker/docker-py

I tried using this old stack overflow example:
[How to bind volumes in docker-py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286481/how-to-bind-volumes-in-docker-py)

I've also tried the `client.volumes.create()` method.

I'm trying to write a class to make docker a bit easier for most people to deal with in python.

```
import docker
VOLUMES = ['/home/$USER', '/home/$USER/Desktop']

def mount(volumes):

       mount_points = []
       docker_client = docker.from_env()

       volume_bindings = _create_volume_bindings(volumes)
       host_config = docker_client.create_host_config(binds=volume_bindings)


def _create_volume_bindings(volumes):
    volume_bindings = {}
    for path in range(len(volumes)):
        volume_bindings[volumes[path]] = {'bind': 'mnt' + str(path + 1),
                       'mode': 'rw'}

    return volume_bindings
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use the [Low-level API client](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#low-level-api)?

If yes, you can try to replace the line

```
docker_client = docker.from_env()
```

with

```
docker_client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
```

That one has the `create_host_config()` method.